# Annoying behavior of a dynamic angular gauge

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I want to do something that can be simplified into the following toy example: I want to dynamically show the count down to a future date on an `AngularGage`. The following code works,

```
x = Dynamic[Refresh[DateDifference[Now,FutureDate,"Minute",UpdateInterval->0.1]
Dynamic[AngularGauge[x,{0,1000}]
```

but the gauge displays an unwanted second hand. How do I get rid of it? The deeper question is about the complicated nature of dynamic variables, as demonstrated in the TreeForm image below. How do you use these kind of variables?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why but if you have a `Quantity[513.2441798845927, "Minutes"]` wrapped with `Dynamic`, then `AngularGauge` can't handle it and shows two inputs, `513.23` and `"Minutes"` (blue one).

I also don't know if that's suppose to happen but here's a work around:

Use `QuantityMagnitude`:

```
Dynamic[AngularGauge[
   Dynamic[Refresh[
     QuantityMagnitude @ DateDifference[Now, Tomorrow, "Minute"], 
     UpdateInterval -> 0.1
   ]], 
 {0, 1000}]
]
```

Or don't use the inner `Dynamic` since there is one outside anyway:

```
Dynamic[AngularGauge[
  Refresh[DateDifference[Now, Tomorrow, "Minute"], 
   UpdateInterval -> 0.1], {0, 1000}]]
```

The former method gives you more flexibility I think.

Comment: So, I guess one of the underlying questions is how to return just the numerical part of a dynamic value that is returned with the unit it is expressed in ...

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe As shown above, you can use `QuantityMagnitude` and `AngularGuge` will digest it well.

Comment: Oh, ok - QuantityMagnitude

Answer (score 3):

It can also be done this way. I recommend it because it avoids passing any complicated dynamic expression to `AngularGauge`.

```
Dynamic[
  AngularGauge[
    Quantity[DateDifference[Now, Tomorrow, "Minute"]], 
    {Quantity[0, "Minute"], Quantity[800, "Minute"]}, 
    GaugeLabels -> "Unit"], 
  UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

[image: timer]

The tooltip confirms that the gauge is dynamically updating.

Comment: I appreciate these answers. I'm learning more than I expected.